# How to display distinct count in a hierarchical menu?

Tags: algolia

I am using instantsearch, hits and hierarchical widgets.

I have the following:

[image]

As you can see, there is a discrepancy between the count in the categories and the number of results we see.

The thing is it shows the count for the number of *grouped* results (ie. there is 3 variants of this camera) while showing one *distinctive* result since I set `distinct` to `true`.

I looked [there](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hierarchical-menu/js/) and did not find anything useful.

How can I make the hierarchical menu display the *right* count?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the parameter [`facetingAfterDistinct`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetingAfterDistinct/?language=javascript#usage-notes). You can provide this parameter to the [`configure`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/js/) widget (if available) or to the [`searchParameters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/js/?language=javascript#widget-param-searchparameters) option exposed on `instantsearch`. Here is an example:

```
const search = instantsearch({
  // ...
  searchParameters: {
    facetingAfterDistinct: true,
  }
});
```